# Библиотеки MD5 или SHA в C++

Tags: sha, c++, md5

Есть ли встроенные библиотеки на C++ или на Qt для вышеуказанного шифрования?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашёл в Qt исходники md5 и sha1, просто надо было лучше поискать.

Answer (score 0):

Встроенные? В смысле такие, которые не надо откуда-то брать? Нет. Ну, если конечно не считать, что почти на всех Linux-машинах есть OpenSSL.. тогда с некоторой точки зрения можно считать, что она встроенная :)

В Qt есть встроенная [CRC16](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qbytearray.html#qChecksum), но это вряд ли вас устроит.

Comment: Блин, мне нужно почти то же самое, только для 32-битного суммирования. (( А в исходном коде её можно где-нибудь найти?

Answer (score 0):

Для Windows есть библиотека CryptoAPI.